# Instagram don't redirect to localhost in Swift but does in navigator

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, instagram

A week ago I had my Instagram login system working really fine. I don't know what happened (recent limitation in iOS or change something with Instagram API...) but I'm not able to login.

In my Instagram application, I have two URIs saved: http://localhost and http://localhost/

I've got my function to make the login. It's something like this:

```
func instagramLogIn()->Void{

    webViewOutlet.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token")!))
}
```

In run this method in viewDidAppear where Instagram login appears:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    instagramLogIn()
}
```

Of course webView outlet's delegate is set in self so I can listen to every change of the webView. So I do this now:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){

    let result = webView.request!.mainDocumentURL

    print(result)

    let result2:URL = URL(string: "/", relativeTo: result)!.absoluteURL


    if result2.absoluteString == "http://localhost/"{
```

This is supposed to be run every time a request ends loading so the first method should redirect to http://localhost/#authToken=MY_AUTH_TOKEN. So in webViewDidFinishLoad() I check if the main URL is localhost and if so I keep doing things. I print "result" and "result2" and what I get is the first url to load (https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token) and "result2" prints "http://www.instagram.com".

It's not redirecting to http://localhost. A days ago it did.

What happen if I open the first url in Safari (in my Mac, not iOS)? It redirects perfectly and I get my auth_token.

So the question is: why is not redirecting in iOS? In Mac I've already an open session.

I don't know what's wrong with this. A couple or days it worked fine.

Comment: Yes I noticed the same thing you are not alone :(

Comment: Many thanks! I was worried :S

Comment: I see it's fixed but I still can't make it work :S